# Proof through Menelaus' theorem of a problem involving medians

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In the figure shown
[image: Triangle Image]

We have $AD$ as median, $F$ is midpoint of $AD$, $BD=BF$. I wish to prove $AE=EF$. I tried to use Menlaus' theorem. but to no use. While doing the ratios taking two different triangles, I got two different values for the same ratio.
For, in traingle $ABD$, we have the transversal $CE$. Using Menelaus', we get
$$\frac{BC}{BD}\cdot\frac{DF}{AF}\cdot\frac{AE}{BE}=1$$
This implies $\frac{AE}{BE}=\frac1{2}\ldots\ldots(1)$.
Now, in triangle $ABG$, we have the transversl $CE$. Again using Menelaus', we get
$$\frac{AC}{GC}\cdot\frac{GF}{BF}\cdot\frac{BE}{AE}=1$$
Which implies that $\frac{AC}{GC}\cdot\frac{GF}{BF}=\frac1{2}\ldots\ldots(2)$.
We take triangle $ACD$, with transversal $BG$ to get
$$\frac{CB}{CD}\cdot\frac{DF}{AF}\cdot\frac{AG}{CG}=1$$
This implies $\frac{AG}{CG}=\frac1{2}\ldots\ldots(3)$.
Using triangle $ACE$ with transversal $BG$ and Menelaus', we get:
$$\frac{AB}{BE}\cdot\frac{EF}{CF}\cdot\frac{CG}{AG}=1$$
which implies that
$\frac{EF}{CF}=\frac1{3}\ldots\ldots(4)$.
Now, using the triangle $BCE$ with transversal $AD$, we have by Menelaus':
$$\frac{AB}{AE}\cdot\frac{EF}{CF}\cdot\frac{CD}{BD}=1$$
which implies $\frac{EF}{CF}=\frac1{3}\ldots\ldots(5)$.

Using the equations $(1)$ through $(5)$, the only things I got are that $AE=\frac{AB}{3}$ and that $EF=\frac{CE}{4}$. Now, how do we proceed? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much simpler approach:

Draw a line l from B parallel with AD. Extend CE and CA from E and A to intersect line l at H and I respectively.In triangle IBC , A is mid point of CI. H is mid point of BI, because F is mid point of AD , $AD||BI$ and $\triangle CAF \sim\triangle CIH$, ALso $\triangle CFD\sim \triangle CHB$. connect A to H. So in triangle IBC, AH connects mid points of sides IC and IB , so it is parallel with BC and quadrilateral AHBD is parallelogram, so we have:

$AH=BD=BF$

Hence quadrilateral AHBF is isosceles trapezoid and E is the intersection of it's diagonals.In this way triangles AHE and EBF are equal, therefore $AE=EF$

Note: I can not attach the figure I constructed due to my problem with this site. I can send you if I have an address.

Comment: Sorry, I just did not get how AH is parallel to BC, as well as how the triangles AHE and BFE are congruent (equal). Also, you are duplicating the point G, I suppose. And moreover, even if AHE and BFE are congruent, we should have AE=BE right, which is wrong. You meant AHE is congruent with EBF(order of vertices)

Comment: I meant AHE is congruent with FBE

Comment: Thanks for the edit. By the way, how did you come up with this, like is there any standard technique for such kind of problems?